# Saving area within a shape (rectangle) as image from multiple powerpoint slides

Tags: python, powerpoint, python-pptx

I'm attempting to grab an image of diagrams constructed within a rectangle on a power point slide deck.  I found python-pptx and am able to identify the shapes on each slide.  Is there any way to expand this to take a snapshot of the area within the rectangle shape and export it as an image?

```
# Auto grab the photos created in Powerpoint

from pptx import Presentation

prs = Presentation('ex.pptx')

for slide in prs.slides:
    print(slide)
        for shape in slide.shapes:
            print(shape)
# Identify shape on each slide, find area within, and save as .png
```

Comment: What platform(s) does it need to run on?

Comment: This just needs to run on a Windows 10 machine

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to be best off looking at a COM32 type of solution, either writing something in VBA or possibly using the `win32com` library in Python if you really want a Python solution.

Either way this is going to fire up a "live" PowerPoint application instance and basically run it by remote control. That sort of thing isn't a great idea server-side, but if it's just for personal productivity it might work fine.

`python-pptx` can't do this sort of thing and probably never will. The rendering engine needs to get involved in this type of work and `python-pptx` is strictly a `.pptx` file editor/generator.

Answer (score 0):

With [Aspose.Slides for Python](https://products.aspose.com/slides/python-net/), you can easily save presentation shapes to images. The following code example shows you how to save all charts from a presentation to PNG images:

```py
import aspose.slides as slides
import aspose.slides.charts as charts
import aspose.pydrawing as draw

with slides.Presentation("example.pptx") as presentation:
    for slide_index, slide in enumerate(presentation.slides):
        for shape_index, shape in enumerate(slide.shapes):
            # Looking for charts, for example.
            if isinstance(shape, charts.Chart):
                # Get a chart image.
                with shape.get_thumbnail() as chart_image:
                    # Save the chart image to PNG.
                    image_path = "chart_image_{}_{}.png".format(slide_index, shape_index)
                    chart_image.save(image_path, draw.imaging.ImageFormat.png)
```

Aspose.Slides for Python is a paid product, but you can get a temporary license or use it in a trial mode to evaluate all features for managing presentations. Alternatively, you can use [Aspose.Slides Cloud SDK for Python](https://products.aspose.cloud/slides/python/). This package provides a REST-based API for managing presentations as well. The code example below shows you how to do the same using Aspose.Slides Cloud:

```py
import asposeslidescloud
import aspose.pydrawing as draw

from asposeslidescloud.apis.slides_api import SlidesApi
from asposeslidescloud.models import *

slides_api = SlidesApi(None, "my_client_id", "my_client_secret")

file_name = "example.pptx"

# Upload the presentation to the default storage.
with open(file_name, "rb") as file_stream:
    slides_api.upload_file(file_name, file_stream)

# Get the number of slides.
slides_info = slides_api.get_slides(file_name)
slide_count = len(slides_info.slide_list)

for slide_index in range(1, slide_count + 1):
    # Get the number of shapes on the current slide.
    shapes_info = slides_api.get_shapes(file_name, slide_index)
    shape_count = len(shapes_info.shapes_links)

    for shape_index in range(1, shape_count + 1):
        shape = slides_api.get_shape(file_name, slide_index, shape_index)

        # Looking for charts, for example.
        if shape.type == "Chart":
            # Get the chart as a PNG image.
            image_path = slides_api.download_shape(file_name, slide_index, shape_index, ShapeExportFormat.PNG)
            print("A chart image was saved to " + image_path)
```

This is also a paid product, but you can make 150 free API calls per month for any purposes.

I work as a Support Developer at Aspose and can answer your questions of these libraries on [Aspose.Slides forum](https://forum.aspose.com/c/slides/).